# How to use HashSet or a similar class with fast search and "get" method?

Tags: java, search, get, hashmap, hashset

JAVA
Eclipse 3.8
"id" is the primary key for Product class. I need to store a list of "Product"s in a data structure which provides fast search like provided by HashSet and also i need to get/retrieve the searched object. Using a HashMap would result in redundant "id"s which is costly.

Comment: What do u mean by redundant "id"s?

Comment: You can't put Product objects in a HashSet?

Comment: Redundant id's really shouldn't be a concern of yours in a Java application;  If your memory budget is that tight, you are probably barking up the wrong tree.  @everyoneElse:  To clarify, I believe he means that the Product class has an 'id' field, which he'd have to duplicate / auto-box in order to define the Keys in a HashMap

Comment: If you need to retrieve the searched object, wouldn't storing a key value pair of the type `<productID, product>` work for you?

Comment: Further to @npinti's answer, if the Product has an Id field, you can do `map.put(product.getId(), product)`, using the Id field from the product as the key.

Comment: Thanks torquestomp. I got the answer from tom. HashSet implements a HashMap as its member. So no worry in directly using a HashMap instead.

Comment: Both a `HashSet` and a `HashMap` will have redundancies, but a `HashMap<Integer, Product>` will additionally create an `Integer` object for each key. A `HasHap<Product, Product>` (mapping each product to itself) will use exactly as much memory as a `HashSet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's HashSet is implemented using a HashMap, so it's also going to have redundancies. If you have done performance testing and found that to be a significant performance hit consider using a high-performance collections library such as [GNU Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) (specifically [TIntObjectHashMap](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TIntObjectHashMap.html)).

Comment: Thanks Tom for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

If your ID is unique (no two objects has the same ID), just define properly the equals() method of your to-be-stored objects and use HashSet instead.

Comment: That doesn't work - you can't retrieve the Product by id that way

Comment: torquestomp: yes, you are right. I forgot about the requirement of "fast search". Sorry for confusion.